# What does it mean that a point depends continuously on a map?

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $f : X \to X$ a continuous map. What does it mean that some points of $X$ depend continuously on $f$ with respect to $C^1$ topology? (I mean certain types of points; for example fixed points etc)

Comment: What is the $C^1$ topology in a metric space?

Comment: I think $d_{C^1}(f, g) = max(d(f, g)), d(f', g'))$.

Comment: (1) The $\max$ will it exists? (2) *How* can you define the derivative in a metric space? (3) And $d(f,g)$?

Comment: I don't know :( I want to show that the fixed point of a contraction depends continuously on the contraction with respect to the $C^1$ topology, but I don't know what does depends continuously on the contraction means.

Comment: You can't define derivatives in a metric space. More structure (a Banach space) is required: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative.

Comment: Ok, I put $X$ a Banach space. What does it mean continuously dependence of the fixed point on $f$ with respect to $ C^1$ topology? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is stated, the problem is vague. Specifying more can be true... or false. Example:
$$f_c(x) = x^2 + c,\qquad x\in[-1,1].$$
If the $c$ are near, the $f_c$ are near in the $C^1$ sense (with any [reasonable definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462901/how-are-c0-c1-norms-defined) of $C^1$-near), but:

- $f_c$ has zero roots for $c>0$,
- $f_c$ has one root for $c = 0$,
- $f_c$ has two roots for $c < 0$.