# Mean Value function theorem on a Riemannian Manifold

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, mean-value-theorem

Suppose you have a Riemannian manifold $M$, a smooth function $\phi: M \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and lastly, two points $p, q \in M$ so that $d(p, q) < \text{inj } M$ where $\text{inj } M$ is the injectivity radius of $M$. It seems that the following inequality is correct

$$
|\phi(p) - \phi(q)| \le d(p, q) \|\phi\|_{C^1}
$$

I had two questions.

How is

- $\|\phi\|_{C^1}$ defined?
- How is the inequality proved?

I think the paper by Hamilton, The inverse function theorem of Nash and Moser, might have my answer inside (Actually Theorem 5.1.3 seems close but yet different from what I want). Due to a limited time to read that paper (although I think there is something much more easier going on here), I would appreciate if you can help me understanding this. Mostly, what I need though is just a reference where this or something similar is discussed.

Comment: Where does this come from?

For the proof, I think the following idea is relevant. Let $\gamma\colon [0,d(p,q)]\to M$ be a length-minimizing geodesic segment from $p$ to $q$, and consider $f(t) = (\phi\circ\gamma)(t)$. Can you go on?

Comment: It's from this paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.08599): On page 15, in the first relation after equation (18) you can find a similar inequality. Here $\epsilon_0$ is the $C^0$ distance between $f_i$ and $g_i$. I am yet not certain how is the $C^1$-norm of $\phi$ defined in this setting.

Comment: Does https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1255941/mean-value-theorem-on-riemannian-manifold help?

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang I think yes. It probably contains the proof of the above as well. I'm not still sure what is the $C^1$-norm of $\phi$ means in our setting though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The $\mathcal{C}^1$-norm on a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ is usually defined as $$\lvert\lvert f\rvert\rvert=\sup_{x\in M}\lvert f(x)\rvert+\sup_{x\in M}\lvert\lvert\nabla f(x)\rvert\rvert$$
where the second term is the norm of the gradient of $f$ with respect to $g$. See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/462901/261022) for reference.

As for the second question, take any path $\gamma$ between $p$ and $q$. Then
\begin{equation}
\phi(p)-\phi(q)=\int_0^1\partial_t\left(\phi(\gamma(t)\right)\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^1g\big(\nabla\phi(\gamma(t)),\dot{\gamma}(t)\big)\mathrm{d}t.
\end{equation}
Taking absolute values and using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality you find
\begin{equation}
\lvert\phi(p)-\phi(q)\rvert\leq\int_0^1\lvert\lvert\nabla\phi(\gamma(t))\rvert\rvert\,\lvert\lvert\dot{\gamma}(t)\rvert\rvert\,\mathrm{d}t\leq\mbox{length}(\gamma)\cdot\sup_M\lvert\lvert\nabla\phi\rvert\rvert.
\end{equation}
The hypothesis on the injectivity radius and the distance between $p$ and $q$ allows us to take in particular a path realizing the distance between the two points.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed help! It was very clear and helpful.

Comment: How did you factor $\nabla \phi$ out in the integral? It's dependent on $t$ right?

Comment: @Lemon: are you referring to the last inequality? It goes like this: we are integrating the product of two functions of $t$, the norm of $\dot{\gamma}$ and the norm of $\nabla \phi$ along $\gamma$. This second piece can be bounded above by a constant (not depending on $t$), the supremum of the norm of $\nabla\phi$. Note that I am assuming the manifold to be compact, I should have written this in the original answer... Anyway, does this make it clearer?

Comment: @JohnnyLemmon yeah sorry I figured out much later. $\nabla \phi$ bounded above from the inside. Just a quickie, but why does $M$ have to be compact here? That we have sup?

Comment: @Lemon yes, the norms defined in that way using "sup" only really make sense on compact manifolds.

Comment: @JohnnyLemmon Hang on, I thought sup always exists even on non-compact domains. So for example, if $M$ is not compact say is unbounded, then sup can be infinity, but that doesn't mean "it doesn't make sense" for sup to be defined right?

Comment: @Lemon yes, what I meant is that on a noncompact manifold the "norm" of a function, defined in that way, could be infinite, so it would not actually be a norm on the space of all smooth functions.